# Android Button like Preference

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, button

I just start learning with Android and construct an APP now.
But I encounter a problem that I want to design a Button with 2 lines and different text style for each line.
How can I do this job and make the Button like a Preference with Text and Summary?

Thanks

Comment: Post the code what you have done so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Test extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        but.setText( formatString( "Line 1\nLine 2" ) );
    }

    private Spannable formatString(String str) {
        int startSpan = str.indexOf("\n");
        int endSpan   = str.length();

        Spannable spanString = new SpannableString(str);

        spanString.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(this,
                R.style.custompoint), startSpan, endSpan,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        return spanString;
    }

}
```